# How to Print and get a confirmation

Tags: winforms, printing, receipt

There is a way to print any content from a Winforms application and get a status of this operation.

The scenario that i have is a winforms bussiness application that need print a receipt of a bussiness transaction and if the receipt is printed with out problems, confirm the bussiness transaction.

If there area any problem (out of paper, paper jam, printer off line, etc) printing the transaction receipt, then roll back the bussiness transaction.

How can I resolve this scenario ?

tks in advance

Comment: Aditionaly, I can not use the print queue of the operating system.
 
The application need to print Sync (send the content and get the answer inmediatly).

Comment: I already get a partial solution using POS for .NET printing funtionality. and this is the optimal solution form my scenario.
 
But the proble using POS for .NET is that only POS printers have OPOS divers for this library.
 
Not every printer model have a OPOS driver, and my scenario require support for any printer.
 
So the question remains if there are any way to print a content like POS for .NET but using any printer (not just OPOS printer drivers)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Winforms will have what you are looking for as a first class feature, however you should be able to use SNMP to query a printers state, and monitor its page count via a background worker.

You can find an open source SNMP library here:
http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/

A more specific example using COM to get a printer's status can be found here:
http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2005/08/08/182.aspx